# Issues with Kompose tool while converting docker compose to k8 mainifest

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

how to resolve issues while converting docker-compose to k8 manifest files.

I am getting errors once use the Konvert tool forbidden errors. any simple way to convert docker-compose to k8 manifest